# Video streams requiring Windows Media Player plugin stopped working

Tags: plugins, media

Video streams requiring Windows Media Player plugin stopped working.
(probably after VLC or/and GNOME Media Player installs - uninstalling did not help)

I have gstreamer installed.

I have Totem, VLC and Gecko plugins. Tried to disable and uninstall each one of them in any available combination,leaving only one of them etc.
Nothing helps.
Tried different browsers - all same. I get "missing plugin"

I have Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Install wine. Use winetricks to install firefox 10 after install flash player and windows media player plugin in windows firefox that you have installed in wine.